# Jquery toLowerCase doesn't work

Tags: javascript

For example, I would have a field called "email_address" within a form and with the following code, it should be able to change it to lower case. I tested it in chromes console and it shows the change, but not in the actual form.

```
$('input[name=email_address]').val().toLowerCase();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing as _"jQuery toLowerCase"_. `toLowerCase()` is part of JavaScript **not** jQuery...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the value back on the element:

```
var $input = $('input[name=email_address]');
var lowerCaseValue = $input.val().toLowerCase();

$input.val(lowerCaseValue);
```

Comment: That works but only when I do it in the console. Do I need a trigger?

Comment: This should work regardless. It all depends on when you invoke this code. Without the surrounding context, it is hard to say why this is not working for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign it back

```
obj = $('input[name=email_address]');    
obj.val(obj.val().toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also allowed only lower case char using events :

```
$('input[name=email_address]').on('keyup blur',function(){ 
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }
);
```